# Google Maps API V3: pass marker coordinate to google directions service request

Tags: google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

Users search my map with the Google places API which adds markers to my map. I have a click event inside each markers infowindow to get directions to that marker. 
**How do I pass the coordinates of the selected marker to my google directions service request?**

So far I declared `var placeLoc = null;` as a global variable. I defined `placeLoc=place.geometry.location;` inside my create marker function. Then I have:

```
function calcRoute() {
 var start = myLatLng;
 var end = placeLoc;
 var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
 });
}
```

The function renders directions to the wrong marker. I am guessing that it is just giving directions to the first marker in the array returned after the search and not the actual marker I selected. How do I provide the directions request the coordinates of a selected marker?

Below is the code that places the search results into the place variable:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
     var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
     // alert("getPlaces returns "+places.length+" places");

    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
         gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    gmarkers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
       var place = places[i];
       createMarker(place);
       bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    // if (markers.length == 1) map.setZoom(17);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function createMarker(options) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    placeLoc = marker.getPosition();
    calcRoute();
  });

  return marker;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not give me the directions to the marker I selected. It still returned directions to another marker in the array. But I do think marker.getPosition() is what I am missing somewhere in my code. I just need to figure out where,

Comment: I found this example: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map4c.htm which I beleive passes the marker location through this code `'<input type="hidden" id="daddr" value="'+name+"@"+ point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() + '"/>';` This code uses the google maps api v2. Will something similar work in V3 or is the getPosition() function what I should be looking to?

Comment: Finally figured it out. It was similar to your answer, the key is to get marker.getPosition into the function that has the event listener that opens the infowindow. I think as your function code stands it should be enough to help people get through this problem. Thanks